# How to change link color on hover and change it back (with per-link styling)?

Tags: html, css, highlight

Each of the links on my website has a unique color, which is defined within the `style` argument within each `<a>` tag. I want to be able to change the background color of each link on the page to aqua and change the text color to white on hover. However, because of the separate color per link, the text color does not change and is overwritten. How can I get around this?

Here is my code:

```css
a {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href=about style="color:cyan">About</a><br>
<a href=how style="color:magenta">How this site was made</a><br>
<a href=changelog style="color:goldenrod">Upcoming Changes & Changelog</a><br>
```

Edit: To clarify, I want the links to remain the color they are, but I want them to change to white on hover, and change back on non-hover. The highlight color change already works.

Comment: I would add a small padding on each link as well. 2px or so.

Comment: I would start by fixing the original issue which is the use of inline style rather than trying to add more issues

Comment: @RickardElimää Thanks for the tip, but this is just a small snippet of my code. The actual content is enclosed in a div and I'm using an external stylesheet. So it has padding on my actual website. I only posted what was important in this case, though.

Comment: @TemaniAfif How else should I style the text so that each link can be its own color? I'm new to HTML so I do not know how to go about this.

Comment: use classes and target your element using selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS variables instead of inline color so you don't have to deal with `!important` and specificity issues:

```css
a {
  color: var(--c,black);
}

a:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href=about style="--c:cyan">About</a><br>
<a href=how style="--c:magenta">How this site was made</a><br>
<a href=changelog style="--c:goldenrod">Upcoming Changes & Changelog</a><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `!important` property so it overrides the inline style

```css
a {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<a href=about style="color:cyan">About</a><br>
<a href=how style="color:magenta">How this site was made</a><br>
<a href=changelog style="color:goldenrod">Upcoming Changes & Changelog</a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `!important` property to override all other declarations:

```css
a {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<a href=about style="color:cyan">About</a><br>
<a href=how style="color:magenta">How this site was made</a><br>
<a href=changelog style="color:goldenrod">Upcoming Changes & Changelog</a><br>
```